# Flushing output to browser, carriage return and overwrite?

Tags: php, carriage-return, output-buffering

I'm experimenting here with output buffering and am stuck on carriage returns, overwrites.

Basically, if I run this snippet in CLI:

```
<?php

$times = 5000;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++)
{
    echo chr(13) . sprintf('Running step %d/%d...', $i, $times);
}
```

It will stay on line 1 and overwrite the contents with actual step information.

Like, on first step the console output will be:

> `> php micro.php`
>   `Running step 1/5000...`

On step 3333:

> `> php micro.php`
>   `Running step 3333/5000...`

After completition:

> `> php micro.php`
>   `Running step 5000/5000...`
>   `>`

As you can see, in total, the program will have only consumed 1 line for it's output.

Now, if I tweak the script for browser and request it from browser:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1');

$times = 50000;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++)
{
    echo chr(13) . sprintf('Running step %d/%d...', $i, $times);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

I get the output while the script is being processed, but, it is not overwritten.

Like, on first step the console output will be:

> `localhost/micro.php:`
>   
>   `Running step 1/5000...`

On step 3333:

> `localhost/micro.php:`
>   
>   `Running step 1/5000...`
>   `Running step 2/5000...`
>   `Running step 3/5000...`
>   `Running step 4/5000...`
>   `...`
>   `Running step 3333/5000...`

After completition:

> `localhost/micro.php:`
>   
>   `Running step 1/5000...`
>   `Running step 2/5000...`
>   `Running step 3/5000...`
>   `Running step 4/5000...`
>   `...`
>   `Running step 3333/5000...`
>   `...`
>   `Running step 5000/5000...`

In total consuming 5001 lines.

How do I carriage return in a browser output to force line overwrite?

Comment: I do not understand your requirements. Could you explain more clearly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: You will not 'get output while script is being processed'. HTTP is synchronous - so you'll see only full executed script result

Comment: @LeGEC see update. And, Alma, yes you will, if you explicitly flush it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't.

The only way I see to implement a progress bar in a browser involves javascript, and ajax requests to poll the server on the progress status.

Answer (score 0):

There's some kind of workaround: On every iteration/operation you can flush javascript which overwrites text inside html element.

You can see the example progressbar in my test app: http://darium.linuxpl.eu/tag/ - to see the progressbar you should upload any csv file and click "generuj"